# which is the best protocol for text chat, voice chat and sharing file

Tags: tcp

In my current semester, I am studying the course of communications and networks. My teacher gave us an assignment to choose the best protocol for three different scenarios. I am new to this course, and I am not 100% sure. Please help me to solve this. Here is the question.

Assume you have two users A and B, who want to communicate with each other over a communication network. The applications they are using for this purpose can either make use of TCP or UDP protocol. Explain which of these protocols (TCP and UDP) will be the best to use in the following circumstances and why?

a) Both A and B want to send chat messages to each other.

b) Both A and B wants to do a voice conversation.

c) A wants to send a file of size 5MB to B.

Answer (score 0):

hi for that above requirement you can done any one of the protocols. i thing both will work fine nicely. the decision on yours the tcp protocol used for connection oriented network that is more secure than udp. mostly udp is used for connection less network. u can able to do the above on the both protocol.

Comment: thanks for your answer, your answer is a little bit useful, but I need more details for each scenario. let us wait for further replies.